# Swift Подключение класса ((coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Доброго времени суток.

При запуске билда ругается на строчку инициализации класса внутри UIViewController

```
class Logic {
..
}
```

(Два разных файла)

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    ..
    let logic = Logic()    //Строчка, на которую ругается дебаг
    ..
}
```

Код ошибки:
    `#1 0x00000001088a5e68 in FirstVC.init(coder : NSCoder) -> FirstVC? at /Users/TrevanPwrd/Desktop/Xcode/iOS/Happy New Year!/Happy New Year!/FirstViewController.swift:40`

Погуглив, я попытался добавить в FirstVC инициализатор, но это не дало результатов

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка? Как исправить? Как инициализировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавив

```
init () {
}
```

в `Login`